# Scala `Application does not take parameters` compile error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to come up with a simple function that takes a function and list of integers and apply the function on every integer in the list -

```
    def IntOps(f: Int => Int)(values: List[Int]): Int = {
     if(values.isEmpty) 0
     //Getting "Application does not take parameters" in values.tail
     else IntOps(f(values.head)(values.tail))
    }
    IntOps(x=> x+x)(List(1, 2, 30)
```

I am getting a compiler error `Application does not take parameters` on `values.tail`, I am beginner to both Functional programming and scala so any pointers or answers to understand this would be great.

Comment: I get "`Int` doesn't take parameters"

Comment: What should IntOps do? I don't see how using a function `Int => Int` you turn a List[Int] into an Int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code has two problems.

```
IntOps(f(values.head)(values.tail))
```

1. Errant parenthesis - `IntOps` takes two parameter lists with one parameter in each.
2. Wrong type of 1st argument - The 1st argument needs to be a function `Int => Int`, which is what `f` is, but you're invoking `f`, which returns an `Int`, which isn't what `IntOps` requires.

Comment: Thanks, that is very clear.. Is there a way I can fix the issue #2 without having an inner function or an anonymous function?

Comment: Well it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do.  If the result you want is a list with new values then `IntOps` needs to return `List[Int]`, not `Int`, and you have to include code that **builds** the new list.  If you want to reduce the input list to a single `Int` then you need, among other things, a received function `f` that takes 2 parameters. One of those parameters will be the current list element, and the other parameter will be the result of the recursive call to `IntOps`.

Comment: You answer helped me fix the issue with an inner function as here https://gist.github.com/gocoolgeek/8369568e514c708990a68a880c8a4951.. Just wanted to try and see if I can get rid of  the `Ops` function

Comment: You **can** get rid of the `Ops` function if `IntOps` were to take 3 arguments.  The 3rd arg could also be supplied with a default value.